# How do I know whether or not my Android app is running in background?

Tags: android, android-activity

There is a WebView in my Android App.

I make a toast to show the loading progress.

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
            super.onProgressChanged(view, progress);

            toast.setText("Loading..." + String.valueOf(progress) + "%");
            toast.show();
        }
    });
```

The problem is that when I press "home" button or start another Activity, it still keep updating and showing the toast.

Is there way to check if the current Activity is showing?

For instance:

```
if(getActivity().isVisible())
   toast.show();
```

Comment: [This](http://www.herongyang.com/Android/Activity-onCreate-and-Callback-Methods.html) might help with understanding the lifecycle of an Android app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set yourself a boolean flag in onStop() which gets called as you are being removed from the screen.

```
private boolean amShowing = false;

protected void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    amShowing = true;
}

protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    amShowing = false;
}
```

when with your if statment you can use

```
if(amShowing) {
   toast.show();
}
```

Comment: Took the words out of the answer box I was typing into :P